# How can i set an object under another by constructor

Tags: javascript, class, object, inheritance, constructor

I have a construcrtor simply like

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
         return "fubar";
    }
}
```

here no problem  when i call `new foo().bar();`

But if I wanna make something like this

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
         function subbar() {
            return "subbar";
         };
    }
}
```

I've tried the versions below but none of them works.

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
         this.bar.subbar() {
            return "subbar";
         };
    }

}

function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
         this.bar.prototype.subbar() {
            return "subbar";
         };
    }
}
```

How can i reach subbar like `new foo().bar().subbar()`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The last two are invalid syntax.

Comment: i expect to reach subbar  like nerw foo().bar().subbar() as in many native functions

Comment: Both answer are right you must expose it in the return, I suggest you to take a look to the Module pattern in JS: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: it will be hard to answer without more information on the expected behavior you want to achieve...

Comment: i really dont understand why this question is downwoted

Answer (score 3):

Just return an object with the inner most function:

```
function foo() {
        this.bar = function() {
            return { subbar: function subbar() {
                return "subbar";
             };
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just return the function without the object:

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
        return function subbar() {
            return "subbar";
         };
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like this: `this.bar()()`  The second set of parens calls the returned `subbar()` function

Since functions are objects, when you call `bar()`, the return value will be the function `subbar()`

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to return an object with a function attached to it.

```
function foo() {
  this.bar = function() {
    return {
      subbar: function() {
        return 'subbar';
      }
    };
  };
}
```